# How to customized ggplot2 geom_point plot according to the another variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

I am trying to customized the geom_point plot and I've attached my dataset example below.

```
# Example of the data
library(ggplot2)
coverage = data.frame("category" = c("A","A","B","B","C","C"), "position" = c(1,4,1,3,2,3), "width" = c(10,4,5,7,2,20))
ggplot(test1, aes(x=position, y=width)) + geom_point(colour="red", size=10, shape=20, alpha=1/3)
```

when I executed this code, I obtained following images

[image]

As you can see the above image, if the position information overlapped, the width value represent the same position, this image was not reflected "category" variable. so, I want to take a image that ordered by "category" value like this images.

[image]

How can I setting the options?

Answer (score 0):

Using `facet_wrap()`

```
ggplot(coverage, aes(x=position, y=width)) + geom_point(colour="red", size=10, shape=20, alpha=1/3) +
  facet_wrap(.~category)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your rapid answer! It's really helpful to me :)

Can I have one more question?? 
Actually, I want to plot my origin data following the same method. 
This data has a 2,918,063,992 lines information, about 52GB file size.
If I have a plenty of time and memory, Is it possible to draw the image ?

Comment: @HenryChiles I'm very cautious with plot about 2.9e8 size data with R. Possibility might depends on type of plot you want.

Comment: @HenryChiles the output will be very cluttered if you want a similar graph like this one. Though it depends largely on the scope of your problem, I think it will be best to take a random sample of the data and then plot it.